# Can I return a value from a watcher? VUE

Tags: vue.js, watch

I have a watcher, and I get an error when I try to return a value from a watcher.
Error is pretty vague: `Coding style found in ...file...`

Is it not possible to do this?

```
@Watch('elementIwantToWatch')
public getColumn() {
    //......
    return column;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to return value from watcher.
Watcher are special reactive hooks which we can utilise to take action on some side-effect, the returned value can't be utilise. Probably you are looking for computed property.

```
computed: {
  getColumn() {
   // return value here
  }

}
```

and in HTML, you can directly use:

```
<div> Column: { getColumn } </div>
```